# INBOX and ACHIEVEMENT button images not showing

Tags: bug

`INBOX` and `ACHIEVEMENT` button images **not showing for my SO account**. I tried it in chrome and firefox. They didn't show up on either of them. But they show on safari.

[image]

You can see in the above image that its empty. But actually there are buttons, better say invisible buttons.See below pic.

[image]

So, when i click on that empty space, the popup shows up. I don't understand why its not working with chrome.It happened today and never had such issue before. I like working on chrome or firefox. It's not a big deal with or with out those buttons.But i just want to know how to revert them.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you accessing via HTTPS? Are you using an ad blocker?

Comment: nope.  And iam using adblocker, but it never troubled before. Thanks

Comment: Turn the ad blocker off. Is everything back to normal? ABP seems to have made an update to their rules that is causing this.

Comment: thanks man.Yeah, it worked.

Comment: I suggest contacting them and asking them to fix their rules.